# Silencing chktex NumDash warnings only within certain commands

Tags: punctuation, chktex

I use numbers with hyphens in them with certain commands. For example:

```
\newcommand*{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{#1}}
```

If I use `\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}` on a line, chktex will warn me that `Wrong length of dash may have been used. [8]`. Is there a way to disable only the dash warning within the arguments to the `\orcid` command? I'm tired of putting `% chktex 8` at the end of each of these lines. The other alternative I can think of is just to add `orcid` to `WipeArg`, which will ignore all warnings but I'd prefer to only ignore the dash warning.

Answer (score 1):

The way that *I* would recommend is to add `\orcid` to `WipeArg`.  There's no way (currently) to disable a single warning within the argument of only some commands. I have thought in the past of allowing regular expressions to happen either before or after `WipeArg` (right now they are after).

I guess you could add `\orcid` to `MathCmd` at which point a single dash is the expected format.  But that changes the warnings that apply—what warnings would you like to still apply to the argument of `\orcid`?

Full Disclosure: I am the current maintainer of ChkTeX, though I haven't been keeping up with bug reports very well in the last bit.  Feel free to open a ticket at https://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?group=chktex to keep track of it.